# Shutting down and sleeping with power button

Tags: windows-10, sleep, shutdown

I would like to make my PC go to sleep mode when I press the power button for no longer than (for example) 2 seconds and shutdown when I press it for longer time.
Is it possible?

My system is Windows 10 and my motherboard is Gigabyte GA-P67A-D3-B3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Power button configuration

> I would like to make my PC go to sleep mode when I press the power button for no longer than (for example) 2 seconds and shutdown when I press it for longer time.
>
> Is it possible?

No it is not possible.

- A short press is configurable (sleep, hibernate or shutown).
- A long press is reserved for a hard shutdown.